# Minus of a variable in C++?

Tags: c++, variables

I have this equation:

`R= 2*(-I dot N)*N + I`

Can I simply type `(-I)` or something similar, or do I have to multiply `I` by -1?

Comment: You could just try, you know?

Comment: +1 for useful comment lol. I just wanted to be sure, however :-)

Comment: You wanted to be sure? Again, you could just try. Write a test and see if it passes.

Comment: @Jason: that would tell you that your compiler supports a unary `-` operator. There's a reason C++ is a standardized language (and that other languages that aren't standardized nevertheless have written definitions): so that you can ask a question like this and learn that *all* C++ compilers support a unary `-` operator.

Comment: That said, there's a wide range between "works on my machine" syndrome, and being too cautious and pedantic to try *anything* without checking the standard ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C++ has a unary minus operator that performs negation.

```
- x
```

This negates `x`, just like `0 - x` or `-1 * x` would negate `x`.  Note that the `-` in `-1 * x` is also the unary minus operator.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need brackets so C isn't confused?

Comment: If you have to ask, you should add brackets so *you* aren't confused the next time you look at it.

Comment: @JamWaffles:  No.  The unary `+` and `-` operators have the highest precedence of all the arithmetic operators (other, non-arithmetic operators have higher precedence though).  There is a [list of operators and a precedence table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Cheers Russell - I'll stop being so nooby in the future :-P

Comment: @Russell:  I'd disagree:  one should have at least a basic understanding of the precedence of operators when programming in C++.  Adding parentheses everywhere can make code much harder to understand.

Comment: @JamWaffles: there is a slight weirdness regarding signed integers in C++, the range they cover is not symmetric, for a n-bits integer the range is [-2**(n-1), 2**(n-1)-1], meaning that negating the minimum value is undefined behavior. You can find the minimum value by including `<limits>` and using `std::numeric_limits<YourInt>::min()`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm pretty sure limits aren't an issue here - `I` is a direction vector, but for this equation to work, `I` must be a unit vector, not a scalar, so all is well :-)

Answer (score 1):

You mention in your comment that:

> `I` is a direction vector

If you're using operators on non-native types, you *can't* assume that they are defined. It depends whether operator overloading has been implemented on the class: if there is a `Vector Vector operator-()` member function

Also, mathematically speaking, `(-I dot N) == -(I dot N)` :)

Comment: Thanks. When I have more time and less on my plate, I'll be implementing operator overloading, so this should sort things out.